# ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small in Tabular Form Oracle Apex 4.2

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am getting below error in one page Tabular Form in Oracle Apex 4.2 in production environment:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

I can not debug in prod so I copied all objects including application in dev and UAT but I am unable to re produce this issue in any of the environment except PROD.

In PROD, its un predictable to understand the root cause.

I am expecting a workaround or any kind suggestion will be much appreciable.

Comment: Enable debug in production, find the culprit, disable debug (if necessary).

Comment: Is it something that support team can do from front end or with code?

Few days back I saw errors occurred in prod from Activity log and got same message which I get on screen:
 ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Comment: Did you copy the data down?  The most likely problem is that you've declared a variable that is too small for the data you're selecting into it (i.e. a `varchar2(30)` local variable for a database column defined as a `varchar2(50)`).  Which would throw this error if a value longer than 30 characters was actually selected.  It may be that only prod has the longer values.

Comment: Right; but, without debugger, it might take *ages* to find what's wrong. Debugger exists for a reason. Talk to user who can login to internal workspace as ADMIN and ask them to enable debugging.

Comment: Many thanks for responses, In the tabular form one select list is fetching record from LOV and with 426 records page loads but when select list LOV exceeds more than or equal to 427 then shows the same message:

report error:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small

Answer (score 0):

some of your varchar item are exceeding the length limit, try to use clob or give more length.