# Issue with SELECT LIST LOV in Tabular Form

Tags: oracle-apex, apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I am facing issue with Select List LOV having values more than 450.
[image]

It works fine when I limit the value by ROWNUM <= 400 or by using POP-UP LOV.
I am trying to find a solution where I don't have to do any deployment or change app from back end.

Comment: The error you posted doesn't seem to have anything to do with the description you provided.  The number of options in a LOV has no relationship to the length of a variable being exceeded.  My guess is that you have some process on your page that declares a variable that is too small and it happens that the longer values are eliminated when you include the `rownum` predicate.  But without a reproducible test case, all we can do is guess at what might be going on.

Comment: @JustinCave Even I was also in same picture but with DEBUG I saw the sql behind the LOV is getting failed. It took time to find this root cause and is almost un-predictable.

I this Pop up LOV has its own session when clicked but Select List appears on screen for all rows in tabular form.

Comment: It seems there is a restriction with Select List but am not aware of.

Comment: @JustinCave please see link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66669303/ora-06502-pl-sql-numeric-or-value-error-character-string-buffer-too-small-in

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on apex.oracle.com?

Comment: I saw your earlier question and made a similar comment.  The error seems to indicate that you've declared a variable that is too small and that there are a relatively small number of values in the table that are large enough to cause that variable to exceed the declared length.

Comment: @JustinCave I can re produce it the issue is happening when we have large values in Select List LOV. When I changed it to Pop up LOV it works fine. Although the ORA error that we get takes to different direction

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem on apex.oracle.com?  It's really hard to debug code that you can't see.  I'd still suspect that you have a data issue but if you can reproduce the problem on apex.oracle.com, someone may be able to determine the actual problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can re produce it the issue is happening when we have large values in Select List LOV. When I changed it to Pop up LOV it works fine.